# Is there a way to add padding to a specific row in grid in Xamarinforms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, mobile-application, xamarin-forms-4

[image]

In the attached image, this whole design is in grid layout, and the rows encircled with pink line and below are my target to add padding to ... Is there a way that I only set the padding once and it applies to all the rows except the first row(containing the shoes image)?

Comment: You could bind the Margin  to a property in your viewmodel. This property would be of type Thickness and by setting it you could give each instance (row) its individual margin

Comment: Actually I need padding not margin ,,, I want the selected rows have padding left and right ...

Comment: Could you maybe post some code? That might help us to get to the bottom of this

Comment: @ShakaibAkhtar Hi , you use padding inside the row to achieve that . If need to change the padding when runtime , binding model can do that .